# Actionscript 2 loop X amount of frames a random number of times

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In ActionScript 2 I'm looking to loop a certain amount of frames a random number of times in a movie clip symbol.

My code right now looks like this:

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)) + 1;
this.onEnterFrame = function() 
{
    while (a != 0)
    {
        if (this._currentframe == 29)
        {
            this.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
        a -= 1
    }
}
```

But this only succeeds in crashing Flash. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do exactly but try an `if` instead of the `while` which I think is the responsible of the crash ...